# Action on jQuery Plugin Is Always Last Option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, contextmenu

My plugin i'm writing is a right click context menu for an internal app, and I can't figure out why this is happening.

Here is my testing code:

```
$('.item').rightClickMenu([
{
  icon:'http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/exclamation.png',
  title:'Alert',
  action:function(){
    alert('Here is an example alert!');
  }
},
{
  icon:'http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/error.png',
  title:'Console.Log',
  action:function(){
    console.log('Here is an example console.log()!');
  }
}
]);
```

The relevant jQuery plugin code is:

```
for(x in items){
          $list.append('<li class="rightClickMenuOption'+x+'"><img src="'+items[x].icon+'">'+items[x].title+'</li>')
            .find('.rightClickMenuOption'+x)
              .bind('click',function(){
                items[x].action();
              });
        }
```

Demo:
http://jsbin.com/uxali4/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will fix it: http://jsbin.com/uxali4/4/edit

You're creating a closure. All of your invoked methods in your `for..in` loop copy the same **parent Context** into the internal `[[Scope]]` property from their **Activation object**. Hence, all methods access the same variable `x`. You need to invoke another function to fix this.

```
for(x in items){
      (function(index) {
        $list.append('<li class="rightClickMenuOption'+index+'"><img src="'+items[index].icon+'">'+items[index].title+'</li>')
          .find('.rightClickMenuOption'+index)
            .bind('click',function(){
              items[index].action();
            });
      }(x));
}
```

**Update**

Have a look at http://jsperf.com/for-in-vs-for

That should demonstrate pretty impressivly the speed difference between `for` and `for..in`

Comment: Please use a normal `for` loop instead of `for...in`. `items` is an array. But +1 anyway :)

Comment: Awesome! you rock. Ill accept your answer in about 3 mins when StackOverflow lets me :)

Comment: @Felix, I hear that a lot about not using for...in's but I still have yet to understand why. Could you point me to something explaining why you shouldn't? I wanna know, just cant seem to find anything :\

Comment: @Oscar: you're welcome. You should follow Felix Kling's advice also. Using a normal `for loop` to iterate over an array is more appropriate. A good reason for that is, `for..in` is **way** slower than a `for` or `while` loop.

Comment: @Oscar Godson: Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description basically `for...in` is used to iterate over object properties. As arrays are objects too, if you specify a custom property on an array, you will iterate over that too, which is not what you want (and other things). Just use `for...in` for objects and `for` for arrays. If you don't want to write so much and if the order does not matter, you can write the for loop as `for(var i = items.length; i--; )`

Comment: Thanks! @jAndy, so it's mainly a speed issue? I never seem to see while() loops anywhere, is there a reason not to use those either?

Comment: @Oscar: not only, but its a good reason not to use it for Arrays. See Felix Klings comment above for some more. See http://jsperf.com/for-in-vs-for

Comment: @Oscar Godson: You're welcome :) No, while loops are fine and are actually the fastest, but less convenient than a for loop.

Comment: @jAndy: I have the feeling we speak in parallel :D :)

Comment: @Felix Kling: yay it's SPOOOOOOKY :p

Comment: StackOverflow really needs "live streams" :) thanks a lot guys! You've just made me a better coder!